# error 400 when sending request from python to telegram

Tags: python, telegram

I got a 400 error while sending a request from python to telegram.

Here is the code:

```py
bot_message = message
bot_token = 'xxx'
bot_chatID = 'xxx'
send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message
response = requests.get(send_text)
```

Here's the message that caused error :

```
sharashahira 2021-01-25 10:37:50 @CIMB_Assists Mana ni kata sampai pkul 4;45pm. Sampai sekaranf error. Boikot cimb clicks app
```

It got "emote" , so I got 400 when send to telegram.

This is the error

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: can't parse entities: Can't find end of the entity starting at byte offset 17"}
```

Comment: I believe you need to do a POST using ```requests.post()``` not ```requests.get()```. There is also a python wrapper for bots that might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can't find end of the entity starting at byte offset 17"

This error is caused by a MarkDown error caused by: `@CIMB_Assists`

The `_` starts an underline syntax, but is never closed. Telegram can't send those messages.

There are 2 ways to fix this;

1. Remove the MarkDown, send the message as HTML:

   ```
   '&parse_mode=HTML&text=' + bot_message
   ```
2. Remove the `_` from the message

   ```
   sharashahira 2021-01-25 10:37:50 @CIMBAssists Mana ni kata sampai pkul 4;45pm. Sampai sekaranf error. Boikot cimb clicks app
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You should add escaping to use markdown format with this character.

The list of characters you must escape is `` ('_', '*', '[', ']', '(', ')', '~', '`', '>', '#', '+', '-', '=', '|', '{', '}', '.', '!') ``

To add a specific for Telegram escaping you can just use [PlainText](https://telegram-text.alinsky.tech/api_reference#plaintext) from [telegram-text](https://github.com/SKY-ALIN/telegram-text):

```
from telegram_text import PlainText

element = PlainText("_text_to_escape_")
escaped_text = element.to_markdown()
escaped_text
'\\_text\\_to\\_escape\\_'
```